# The number of combinations of members of the board of directors with at least one physician

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

This is an exercise from a textbook. I have come up with a solution but not sure if this is the best, please give your view.

**Problem**

The board of directors of a pharmaceutical corporation has $10$ members. An upcoming stockholder's meeting is scheduled to approve a new slate of company officers (chosen from the $10$ board members).

Three members of the board of directors are physicians. How many slates comprise of at least one physician?

Suppose each slate have $4$ positions.

**My approach**

Combinations with at least one physician = All possible combinations - Combinations without any physician.

Comment: You've used the word *permutation* in the title, but that would involve an ordered sequence of items.  The problem statement suggests to me *combinations* are the issue, choosing a *subset* of the board (to be the "slate of company officers").  But there seems to be missing information, and perhaps you are right about the order of the items being important.  For example, how big is a slate of company officers?  If it were of size ten, that would mean everyone on the board is included.

Comment: @hardmath I don't insist on permutation if it's a wrong word. Suppose we have 4 positions, but the number of positions does not matter as I have presented an abstract version of the problem.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  The order of selection does not matter here.  Therefore, it should be *selections* with at least one physician = all possible *selections* of four of the ten board members - *selections* with no physicians.  You should be using *combinations* rather than *permutations*.  Please edit your question to show us what result you obtain so that we can check your work.

Comment: The approach is sound.  Are you able to follow it through to a solution?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks. I've fixed the wording. I meant the combinations.

Comment: @hardmath Supposing the number of positions are 4, the number of combinations without physicians should be 7*6*5*4 as we need to exclude physicians from calculation. Right?

Comment: The number of selections without physicians is actually $\binom{7}{4} = \frac{7!}{4!3!} = \frac{7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4!}{3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 \cdot 4!} = \frac{7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5}{3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}$ since the order of selection does not matter.  In your calculation, the order of selection matters.

Comment: This exercise appears in the book right before presenting the Binomial‌ Theorem and I‌ suppose the author wants to prepare the learner for such calculation that I‌ failed at. Thanks. Useful discussion. @N.F.Taussig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, your strategy is correct.  However, it looks like you would benefit from distinguishing between how to count permutations, which count arrangements, and combinations, which count subsets.

Let's look at the number of unrestricted selections.  There are $10$ ways to select the first person, $9$ ways to select the second person, $8$ ways to select the third person, and $7$ ways to select the fourth person.  Thus, there are
$$10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7$$
ordered selections of four of the ten board members, that is, there are
$$P(10, 4) = 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 = \frac{10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6!}{6!} = \frac{10!}{6!} = \frac{10!}{(10 - 4)!}$$
$4$-permutations of the ten board members.

However, selecting Anne, Brian, Claudia, and David in that order results in the same selection of company officers as selecting Brian, Claudia, Anne, and David in that order.  Since there are $4! = 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1$ orders in which we could choose the same four of the ten people, there are
$$\frac{10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7}{4!} = \frac{10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6!}{4!6!} = \frac{10!}{4!6!} = \binom{10}{4}$$
ways to select a subset of four of the ten board members to serve as company officers, that is, there are
$$\binom{10}{4}$$
$4$-combinations of the ten board members.

Similarly, there are
$$\binom{7}{4} = \frac{7!}{4!3!}$$
ways to select four of the seven board members who are not physicians.

Consequently, the number of ways of selecting four company officers from the ten board members so that at least one physician is selected as a company officer is
$$\binom{10}{4} - \binom{7}{4}$$
which is equal to the number of ways of selecting a subset of any four of the ten board members minus the number of ways of selecting a subset of four of the seven board members who are not physicians.